# Terminology for games with incomplete information and no prior beliefs

Tags: pr.probability, gt.game-theory

Can anyone please tell me what is the term used for games with incomplete information and there are no prior beliefs about other players' private information.

For example, let $ v_i(a_i,\theta_i) $ be the utility function of the player $ i $ and $ a_i $ be decided for each player some how. $ \theta_i $ be the private information for player $ i $. Player $ i $ has no belief (no knowledge of probability distribution) about others' private information except that it is a real number. Few authors call such games to be pre-Bayesian games. But there seems to be no standard. It would be great if any one can let me know this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Uncertainty in the absence of a prior distribution is sometimes called [Knightian Uncertainty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knightian_uncertainty) in economics. There are a couple of recent papers studying how to deal with knightian uncertainty in mechanism design. See for example:

[The Knightian Truthfulness of Classical Mechanisms](http://people.csail.mit.edu/silvio/Selected%20Scientific%20Papers/Mechanism%20Design/The%20Knightian%20Truthfulness%20of%20Classic%20Mechanisms.pdf)

[Knightian Auctions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.1147)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Knightian Auctions seems to consider scenarios where the player $ i $ has uncertainty over her private information. I was looking for scenarios where the player $ i $ knows her private information precisely but has no prior beliefs about others' private information.